# Does a login need to be created on MSSQL Always On replica before being granted roles on the primary?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, logins

Consider a SQL Server Login `MyLogin` that exists on `PrimaryServer` but not `SecondaryServer` in an Always-On Availability group. `MyLogin` has a number of roles already assigned.

If the login `MyLogin` is later created on `SecondaryServer` using the hashed password and SID from `PrimaryServer`, will it automatically have the same roles on the database mirrored on `SecondaryServer`?

Does it matter that the permissions were granted on the database on the `PrimaryServer` before the login was created on `SecondaryServer`?

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what you need to do--create the login with same name and SID on all primaries.

Comment: My question is about whether the order matters between creating the login on the secondary and granting permissions on the primary. If we CREATE LOGIN on the secondary after it's already got DB-level permissions on the primary, will it automatically have those same permissions on the secondary? I think the answer is that the order does not matter because the SIDs are used to link - but am looking for a definitive answer. Many Thanks!

Comment: Correct, order does not matter.  As long as the SIDs match, it doesn't matter whether you create the login on the primary or secondary first.  Don't overanalyze it.  Very easy to test if you have a non-production environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the login is created first.  The only important thing is that the SIDs match.  All permissions, role memberships, etc. that are assigned to the associated users on databases in the availability group on the primary will be effective on the secondaries for the login with the same SID.

Comment: an important point, server level permissions for primary will not be effective on secondary.